# Azure Function trigger for Dataverse

Tags: azure, azure-functions, dataverse

I have a Dataverse table in which few columns are updated through a Power App.

When this update happens, I want to update the same data in ADP through an Azure Function.

So my question: is it possible to have a trigger in Azure Function for Dataverse updates?

Comment: No, nothing is available at this point. Azure LogicApps can be made to respond to Dataverse updates - but not functions....

Comment: I agree with marc_s that there's no default trigger, But you can refer this Blog -https://brunolucas.blog/2022/09/21/using-azure-functions-to-integrate-with-dataverse-azure-functions-v4-and-dataverse-client-with-msal/ to integrate dataverse with Azure Functions and call it via Http Trigger

Comment: Thanks guys
My objective is not to call Dataverse from Functions, but get changes in Dataverse into the Functions and have  the Function call an external system

Comment: Once you connect your Dataverse with Functions via Logic Apps or Functions Http Trigger, You can write your custom code in Functions or add custom logic in Logic app to update your table or vice versa

Comment: Even Logic Apps works on consumption based model and is serverless like Functions

Comment: Refer here -https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connect-common-data-service?tabs=standard

Answer (score 1):

I would start with this article: [Azure integration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/developer/data-platform/azure-integration)

Azure Functions have built in triggers for Event Hubs, Event Grid, Service Bus Topics and HTTP triggers (WebHooks). So the question is how you want to raise the event from dataverse and what frequency these events might be.

A [dataverse plugin](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/developer/data-platform/azure-integration#plug-ins) gives you the most flexibility of all these options, you could call a function HTTP trigger directly from a plugin.

This is another great article for setting up a Web Hook via functions: [Invoke a WebHook from a plug-in or workflow activity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/developer/data-platform/use-webhooks#invoke-a-webhook-from-a-plug-in-or-workflow-activity)

You could also use a logic app to call your function, again the easiest way is via HTTP triggers but depending on scale and frequency you might prefer to use a queue based or event-hub based solution.